# sum of reciprocal power-1

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I found this in my old notebook

$$\sum_{n \text{ perfect power}} {\frac{1}{n-1}} = 1$$

and this was my "proof"

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots
&=\frac{1}{1}+\left(\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots \right)+\left(\frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots \right)+\left(\frac{1}{5^1}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\cdots \right)+\cdots\\
&=\frac{1}{1}+\sum_{n>1 \text{ not a perfect power}}{\frac{1}{n-1}}
\end{align}
$$

Thus

$$
\sum_{n \text{ perfect power}} {\frac{1}{n-1}}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots-\sum_{n>1 \text{ not a perfect power}}{\frac{1}{n-1}}=1
$$

Is this proof valid?  if not can someone provide a proof?

Comment: What is a "perfect power"? I'm not familiar with that term. Do you mean just numbers that are powers of primes?

Comment: Wouldn't you want terms like $\frac 1 {2^2-1}$ instead of what you have?

Comment: @MPW no, any power>2 of an integer

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be $\frac1n$ instead of $\frac1{n-1}$

Comment: Yes, because the geometric series sum to 1/(n-1); for example 1/2+1/4...=1/(2-1)

Comment: To avoid text duplications, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach-Euler_theorem .

Comment: Great thanks. How do I close this question?